# get pandas dataframe column datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime, datetimeformatinfo

How can we get the format of datetime column in Pandas dataframe?

```
# This is how we set!
df["Date"] = df["Date"].strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
```

Now, how do I get it? as

```
df['Date'].?????

>>> "%m-%d-%Y"
```

Comment: so you have a string that represents a date (and time) and you want to derive the format? You could basically test a bunch of format directives and see if one parses the string - but at some point, I think you'll run into ambiguities (no matter how you do it): e.g. '10/11/12' could be y-m-d, d-m-y etc.